# How does #delay work for Verilog non-blocking statements?

Tags: verilog, delay

What will be printed for `A` and `B` in the second `$display` statement?

```
module blocking;

reg[0:7] A, B;

initial begin
   A = 3;
   #1 A = A + 1; 
   B = A + 1;
   $display("Blocking: A= %d B= %d", A, B ); // A = 4, B = 5
   A = 3;
   #1 A <= A + 1;
   B <= A + 1;
   #1 $display("Non-blocking: A= %d B= %d", A, B ); // A = ?, B = ?
end
endmodule
```

How does event scheduling in Verilog work with respect to delays and non-blocking statements?

Comment: I did and for the second $display, I get A = 4 and B = 4. How the delays get scheduled is what I do not understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have `#1` before the second `$display` statement, it will be executed in the next cycle after `A` and `B` are settled.

Say we are at cycle #1.

```
A = 3; // at #1
#1 // (does not matter) --> #2
A <= A + 1; // #2 will do A + 1 and wait till the end of the cycle 
B <= A + 1; // #2 same as above
// at the end of the cycle #2 (nba scheduling bucket) before switching to #3 
//    A and B will be assigned '4'
#1 // --> #3
// new values of A and B are available here (4)
$display("Non-blocking: A= %d B= %d", A, B );
```

Answer (score 2):

In the 2nd `$display`, since you have put the display in another timeslot (with `#1`), the updated value of `A` & `B` will be printed.

```
module blocking;
   reg[0:7] A, B;
   
   initial begin
     A = 3;
#1   A = A + 1; 
     B = A + 1;
     $display("Blocking: A = %0d B = %0d", A, B ); // A = 4, B = 5
     A = 3;
#1   A <= A + 1;
     B <= A + 1;
#1   $display("Non-blocking: A = %0d B = %0d", A, B ); // A = ?, B = ?
   end
endmodule
```

Output:

```
Blocking: A = 4 B = 5
Non-blocking: A = 4 B = 4
```

But if you put the `$display` in the same timeslot (without `#1`), then the unupdated values of `A` & `B` will be printed.

```
module blocking;
   reg[0:7] A, B;
   
   initial begin
     A = 3;
#1   A = A + 1; 
     B = A + 1;
     $display("Blocking: A = %0d B = %0d", A, B ); // A = 4, B = 5
     A = 3;
#1   A <= A + 1;
     B <= A + 1;
     $display("Non-blocking: A = %0d B = %0d", A, B ); // A = ?, B = ?
   end
endmodule
```

Output:

```
Blocking: A = 4 B = 5
Non-blocking: A = 3 B = 5
```

The reason for that is scheduling of events in Verilog.

`$display` is scheduled in the *active region*, which is before the *NBA (Non Blocking Assignment) region* and hence it will have the original values of the nonblocking assigned signals in the same timeslot.